# How to get a valid filtered model from a Backbone Collection?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm sure I make one of these Backbone newbie mistakes but after a hour of searching around I didn't found a solution.

Here's the problem: When I try to get a filtered model from my collection theres a type error "productCollection.getProductByName("M020012").toJSON is not a function".

But if I change the filter method to a simple "return this.at(0)" I get a valid model.

Why is that and what is the solution?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzeHb/133/)

```
var products = [{
    "name": "M020013",
    "gender": "M",
    "pictures": [{
        "picture": {}}]},
{
    "name": "M020012",
    "gender": "M",
    "pictures": [{
        "picture": {}}]},
{
    "name": "M020011",
    "gender": "M",
    "pictures": [{
        "picture": {}}]}
];

var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Product,
    getProductByName: function(productName) {
        //return this.at(0);

        return this.filter(
            function(product) {
            return product.get('name') === productName;
        });
    }
});

var productCollection = new ProductCollection();

productCollection.on('reset', function() {
    console.log('reset');
    console.log(productCollection.getProductByName('M020012'));
    console.log(productCollection.getProductByName('M020012').toJSON());
});

productCollection.reset(products);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `filter` returns an array of models. And an Array in javascript does not have a `toJSON` function.

Since you want to return a model instead of an array, then you can use the `find` in place of `filter`. The find method returns the first model that matches the criteria

Here's what the code would look like:

```
getProductByName: function(productName) {
  return this.find(function(production) {
    return production.get('name') === productName;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks @muistooshort, I updated my answer to reflect your suggestion